# ForeignKey Assignment - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

although this is a stupid question I am going to go ahead and ask.

I currently have models for 'clients' and 'emails' within Django. I am wondering if the correct cardinality would be to have a ForeignKey pointing toward an instance an email through the 'clients' model. I.e, I have an 'emails_sent' value that points toward an instance within the 'email' model.

Comment: Show us your models and tell us what you are trying to archive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `ForeignKey` from the `Email` model to the `Client` model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Email(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='emails_sent'
    )
```

for an `Email` object `my_email`, you can get the client with `my_email.client`. Furthermore you can get all the emails attached to a `Client` object `my_client` with `my_client.emails_sent.all()`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Email` instead of <s>`emails`</s>.

Comment: That's a better idea. Appreciate the advice.